# How can I get the Text value of a TextBox whose Name gets assigned at runtime?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

I am creating a **TextBox** with the following code:

```
TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
textBox.Name = propertyName;
textBox.Text = value;
textBox.Width = FormControlColumnWidth;
textBox.SetResourceReference(Control.StyleProperty, "FormTextBoxStyle");

sp.Children.Add(textBox); //StackPanel
FormBase.Children.Add(sp);
```

On a **button click**, I want to get the text value of that text box, but I can't specify in code:

```
string firstName = FirstName.Text;
```

since "FirstName" will be defined at runtime. So **how do I get the text value of the Textbox without knowing the name of the textbox at compile time?**

The following is what I have so far but it says that it can't find "FirstName" even though it gets defined at runtime:

```
private void Button_Save(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var db = Datasource.GetContext())
    {
        var item = (from i in db.Customers
                        where i.Id == TheId
                        select i).SingleOrDefault();

        item.FirstName = ((TextBox)FindResource("FirstName")).Text;
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

## REPRODUCABLE EXAMPLE:

I posted a full reproducable example of this problem here: [Why can't I access a TextBox by Name with FindName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755377/why-cant-i-access-a-textbox-by-name-with-findname), perhaps easier to analyze.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest solution would probably to keep a reference to your textbox somewhere in your code. Just add a

```
private TextBox _textbox
```

at the top of your class and set it to the TextBox you add in your code. Then you can refer to it in your Button_Save event handler.

Comment: +1 for the simple answer. Just storing references to dynamically created controls is in most cases the best choice, rather than searching components by name.

Comment: But this is a dynamic form and depending on the object read in, there might be 1 textbox or 50 textboxes, so I can't make a property for each one without knowing how many there will be.

Comment: Use a Dictionary<string, TextBox> or even a Dictionary<string, UIElement> then. Use the name of the control as the key and retrieve the control you need.

Answer (score 3):

You can retrieve it like this:

```
TextBox tb=(TextBox)Children.First(w=>w.Name=="FirstName");
```

Not sure what that `sp` in your code is, but if you really need the 2nd level of controls, you could run a foreach loop over the first level then search by name on the second level.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question is you have to use `this.RegisterName("FirstName", textBox);` which is explained here: [Why can't I access a TextBox by Name with FindName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755377/why-cant-i-access-a-textbox-by-name-with-findname)

Comment: RegisterName seems to work as long as you use the FindName method and not FindResource.

Answer (score 1):

You can find any element using [FindName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname.aspx):

```
 var c = (FrameworkElement)this.FindName("somename");
```

Comment: this gives me c=null, although it works if I put <TextBox Name="FirstName" Text="testing"/> in the XAML.

Comment: I posted a full example showing this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755377/why-cant-i-access-a-textbox-by-name-with-findname

Answer (score 0):

I can't write comments, so this is as a reply to your comment.

Why not use a

```
Dictionary<string, TextBox>
```

as a class property?
that way you can keep references to an indefinite number of textbox instances in the class AND access them easily by name in the dictionary?