# Why can't I access a TextBox by Name with FindName()?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

Why does **FindName()** return **null** in the following example?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestDynamicTextBox343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <StackPanel>
        <Border >

            <DockPanel x:Name="FormBase" LastChildFill="True">

            </DockPanel>

        </Border>

        <Button Content="Save" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace TestDynamicTextBox343
{
    public partial class Window1 : Window
    {
        public Window1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
            sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;

            TextBlock textBlock = new TextBlock();
            textBlock.Text = "First Name: ";

            TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
            textBox.Name = "FirstName";
            textBox.Text = "test";

            sp.Children.Add(textBlock);
            sp.Children.Add(textBox);
            FormBase.Children.Add(sp);

        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox tb = (TextBox)this.FindName("FirstName");
            Console.WriteLine(tb.Text);
        }
    }
}
```

## Addendum to Answer:

Thanks a lot, Bruno, that worked well. In order not to add the same name twice, I wrap it with this:

```
void RegisterTextBox(string textBoxName, TextBox textBox)
{
    if ((TextBox)this.FindName(textBoxName) != null)
        this.UnregisterName(textBoxName);
    this.RegisterName(textBoxName, textBox);
}
```

Or if you will be registering anything other than TextBoxes, a generic version:

```
void RegisterControl<T>(string textBoxName, T textBox)
{
    if ((T)this.FindName(textBoxName) != null)
        this.UnregisterName(textBoxName);
    this.RegisterName(textBoxName, textBox);
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is related to [WPF XAML Namescopes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx).

Because you add elements to parsed element trees, you need to call [`RegisterName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.inamescope.registername.aspx).

```
        ...
        TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
        textBox.Name = "FirstName";
        textBox.Text = "test";

        this.RegisterName("FirstName", textBox);
        ...
```

> Adding Elements to Parsed Element
>   Trees
>
> Any additions to the element tree
>   after initial loading and processing
>   must call the appropriate
>   implementation of RegisterName for the
>   class that defines the XAML namescope.
>   Otherwise, the added object cannot be
>   referenced by name through methods
>   such as FindName. Merely setting a
>   Name property (or x:Name Attribute)
>   does not register that name into any
>   XAML namescope. Adding a named element
>   to an element tree that has a XAML
>   namescope also does not register the
>   name to the XAML namescope. Although
>   XAML namescopes can be nested, you
>   generally register names to the XAML
>   namescope that exists on the root
>   element, so that your XAML namescope
>   location parallels the XAML namescope
>   that would have been created in an
>   equivalent loaded XAML page. The most
>   common scenario for application
>   developers is that you will use
>   RegisterName to register names into
>   the XAML namescope on the current root
>   of the page. RegisterName is part of
>   one important scenario for finding
>   storyboards that will run as
>   animations. For more information, see
>   Storyboards Overview. If you call
>   RegisterName on an element other than
>   the root element in the same object
>   tree, the name is still registered to
>   the element nearest the root, as if
>   you had called RegisterName on the
>   root element.

Comment: I didn't get if i should register all names i want to find with the FindName() function. Should I?

Comment: @LorenzoSciuto Only those you need, and specifically the ones that will be targeted by animation.