# C# Windows Store App - Find resource on xaml

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, c#

If i have 9 TextBlock declared on the XAML file like this:

```
<TextBlock Name="cellText_00" Tag="0"/>
<TextBlock Name="cellText_01" Tag="1"/>
<TextBlock Name="cellText_02" Tag="2"/>
<TextBlock Name="cellText_20" Tag="3"/>
...
<TextBlock Name="cellText_22" Tag="8"/>
```

There is a way to interact with it from the .cs getting exactly the desired tag element?

For instance is it possible to give all the same name and get it in this way:

```
TextBlock tb = get(cellText,0);
```

where the first field is the name and the second one is the tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use the same name for many controls.
However there is a workaround: using the FindName method:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname(v=vs.95).aspx

There [Why can't I access a TextBox by Name with FindName()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755377/why-cant-i-access-a-textbox-by-name-with-findname)
you can find an example and a solution related to namespaces issues.

FindName uses a string to retrieve the control. So you can do something like this: `FindName("cellText_" + identifier);` and take the element you need.

Answer (score 0):

@Sandrouos, I don't think he's using the same name.

This blogpost explains it perfectly:

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/09/how-to-access-named-control-inside-xaml.html

Comment: I actually did not know about the existence of this FindName() method...using different names with the "_i" index ending i got the trick! :) Thanks both!